# How to change the layout height of relative layout in Android Studio 2.3.3?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I'm a beginner of Android programming and currently learning Android Basics at Udacity. On Part Two of the course there's a sample birthday card app making. The instructor showed to use

```
 <RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

But Android Studio keeps on changing it to

```
<RelativeLayout 
   android:layout_height="0dp"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
   tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />
```

and I'm also not able to use the `android:layout_alignParentBottom="True"`

Answer (score 1):

It comes cause your root layout is `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout`
if you want to set `match_parent` to the height and width of relative layout goto your layout design page and do this like image:

[image]

**solution 2**

Change your root layout from `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` to `LinearLayout` or other `Viewgroups` like `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio 2.3.3 , main root layout is `constraint` layout so remove it and use `relative/linear` layout instead.

```
<RelativeLayout 
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
  />
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this which changes the layout height and width to match parent , which is the available screen.

`<RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" />`

or the below which specifies the height and width value in dp , change the number and it changes the size of the layout.

NB:make sure the layout is not in a Constraint layout.

`<RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="150dp"
  android:layout_height="100dp" />`

Answer (score -3):

This is due to new version of the android studio you are using. Just code
so that your whole container will be filled with the relative layout

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't worked. Anyways thanks for the help 